# How can I test whether an empirical discrete distribution is symmetric?

Tags: discrete-data, symmetry

For example, I have a distribution with mean = 55.46; med = 54.5; mode = 45. The Shapiro-Wilk is non significant, the data are unimodal, and there is no significant skew or kurtosis.

At a glance, the mode looks different from the mean and median. Does the non significance of the Shapiro-Wilk etc. mean that they are the same? If so, why bother discussing equivalence of the mean, median and mode, since it's not telling us any new information. If not, how to you work out the cutoffs for these numbers? How close is close enough?

Comment: Symmetric distribution is not the same as mean = median = mode (as your title implies). For example, there can be symmetric bimodal distribution where mean =median but the two do not equal mode.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I'm doing a stats assignment and I'm trying to fill in a table that has "Symmetry (equivalence of mean, median, and mode)" as one of the blanks. I can find all the numbers I need in the SPSS output, I just don't know how to decide if they are equivalent or not.

Comment: There can be asymmetric distributions with mean, median and mode equal  and they need not be pathological. For example, binomial distributions often qualify. More seriously, near equality of these measures doesn't rule out a small fraction of outliers which could dominate analysis. That is a bigger deal than the result of Shapiro-Wilk. What's the sample size here?

Comment: Whether an empirical dataset (I gather from your description that you are talking about empirics; please correct me if you aren't) is unimodal will depend on the kernel bandwidth you use to smoothe it.

Comment: The sample size is 56. I've got another box in the table to put the outliers. I don't know what you mean by "empirical dataset". I mean it's unimodal as in there is one score which occurs the most frequently, that's clear from the SPSS output.

Comment: This is a psychology stats question, by the way, if that makes a difference

Comment: Are your data all integer? Your later comments suggest this. If so, then my earlier comment is not relevant - and the Shapiro-Wilks test is not appropriate. (You *know* that discrete data are not normally distributed.)

Comment: Yes the data are all integer. I don't know what difference that would make, it's interval numeric data. They've given us the data set and asked us to do tests of normality, among other things, and report the Shapiro-Wilks test results

Comment: The [Shapiro-Wilk test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) tests for normality. If your data are inherently integer, then they *cannot* be normally distributed. So Shapiro-Wilk asks a question you *already know* the answer to. Re the initial question about symmetry: can you edit your question to include your data?

Comment: And re what I mean by "empirical dataset": I mean that you are testing whether an *empirically observed* sample comes from a symmetric distribution. The contrast would be to determine whether a *theoretical* distribution is symmetric or not. For instance, a mixture of a $N(0,1)$ and a $N(5,1)$ distribution with equal weights will be symmetric (but certainly not unimodal), while a mixture with weights 0.49 and 0.51 will not by symmetric any more - but if all you have is a sample from such a mixture, you may not be able to detect the (slight) asymmetry.

Comment: This question remains difficult to understand because we don't know what you've been taught and what the expectations are. As several comments already imply, it is hard to discuss these questions even at intemediate level without mentioning complications and exceptions that are possible, or even common, but often not emphasised in elementary or introductory courses.

Comment: FWIW, my own view is that teaching Shapiro-Wilk at an introductory level often produces as many learning difficulties as it solves, but that's true of a lot of statistics learning. Learning statistics is highly spiral: as you revisit even basic topics you continually revise your view of what's crucial. Even what's unimodal is a judgement call as often a secondary peak on a histogram will be dismissed by experienced people as likely to be a sampling quirk. Not that this answers your question....

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up making an appointment with my lecturer to discuss it, and she just said the numbers should be exactly the same for mean, median and mode. I asked about 18, 18, 18.3 (which i have for one particular variable) and she said it's close enough. Doesn't seem very scientific, but obviously close enough is good enough for this particular assignment